# What scores should a student get on the Chinese HSK(x) exam before moving onto HSK(x+1)?

Tags: chinese, hsk

Disappointingly, I recently failed the HSK6 (listening: 52; reading: 63; writing: 55); usually 60% is considered a pass.  (Yes, I'm quite aware it's insanely hard.)

I previously did well on the HSK5 (listening: 86; reading: 74; writing: 88), enough for me to feel like it's "done", thus immediately afterwards I moved onto the HSK6.  However, I'm getting the impression that language learning tests are not like the tests I took in university, where if you "pass" you continue onwards.  Maybe I should have kept studying HSK5 for longer, even after I passed the exam.

I'm interested in a ballpark idea of when one should move onto the next level.

**Question**: What scores should a student get on the Chinese HSK(x) exam before moving onto HSK(x+1)?

I'm aware this is an opinion-seeking question, so hopefully answers can be backed up with references and/or expertise.